# Android XML: Centering Horizontally On Bottom

Tags: android, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    >

<TextView 
    android:text="Title" 
    android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textSize="30px" 
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    >
</TextView>

<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60px">

<Button 
    android:text="Choose a Story" 
    android:id="@+id/choose" 
    android:layout_width="150px" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="1px">
</Button>

<Button 
    android:text="Info" 
    android:id="@+id/info" 
    android:layout_width="150px" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="1px">
</Button>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In this code, as you can see, there is a title, 2 linear layouts, and 2 buttons that are inside a linear layout. What I'm trying to do is center the 2 buttons. No matter what I do, I can never get the 2 buttons to be centered at the bottom with a height of 60px.

In the end I'm trying to make the text centered both vertically and horizontally, and have the 2 buttons on the bottom centered horizontally. What do I need to change?

Heres a picture of what it looks like in the Layout Editor.
[image]

Comment: Unrelated side note - using raw pixel values is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Related question - what is included in the "no matter what I do"? Setting the layout_gravity to "center"?

Comment: Setting layout_gravity to the LinearLayout on the buttons to center_horizontal does not fix the problem.

Comment: How big is the main layout itself? Does your text view span the entire width of the display? And what does it look like in the layout editor?

Comment: The main layout is just fill_parent. My TextView is wrap_content. And I'll take pic in just a second.

Comment: Any help? Still not working. I tried jwriteclub's way. No luck though

Comment: I don't see the picture? In any case, my guess was that if the main layout doesn't actually fill the entire screen, then you won't be centered on the screen either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On your *inner* linear layout, set the `layout_gravity`.

Here's one solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    >
<TextView 
    android:text="Title" 
    android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textSize="30dip" 
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dip"
        >

    <Button 
        android:text="Choose a Story" 
        android:id="@+id/choose" 
        android:layout_width="0dip" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <Button 
        android:text="Info" 
        android:id="@+id/info" 
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

In general, you should style the outermost component (container) which will then position all of its children accordingly. As a side not, this layout would be achieved using just a single (or pair, depending on exactly what you're trying to do) or `FrameLayout`s, which would significantly reduce the layout overhead. While there's nothing *wrong* with `LinearLayout`, it *is* surprisingly computationally expensive.

Comment: You say this works? For some reason, it just appears quite similar to the picture I took above. One difference is the "Choose Story" button covers about 60% of the screen and the info button is smaller and vertically offset by about 10px. Should I take a picture of how it ended up to look like using your script?

Comment: Whoops, I guess that my original solution with an outer `LinearLayout` doesn't work. Fixed it with a `FrameLayout`.

Comment: Also, depending on how you're using the layout, you can replace the root `FrameLayout` with a `merge` tag for even less layout complexity.